# API Integration

Tags: xml, api, curl

Im new here and Im not a programmer but learning along the way. I have come up against a problem but in your explanation (if any - thanks) dont presume that I know. Hope you can help me solve this. Here are the details:

Im trying to integrate Interpire EmailMarketer with iDevAffiliate scripts.

When I register a new member at iDev it informs IEM and addds the new member to the email list.

The issue is that I have to manually input the email address, first name and last name.

In iDev the form fields use the following:

```
$f_name = check_type('f_name');
$l_name = check_type('l_name');
$email = check_type('email');
```

The actual iDev API code/call? is this:

```
$xml = '<xmlrequest>
<username>admin</username>
<usertoken>79fc84383811o000fggYYgsui41e5eb</usertoken>
<requesttype>subscribers</requesttype>
<requestmethod>AddSubscriberToList</requestmethod>
<details>
<emailaddress>email@mydomain.com</emailaddress>
<mailinglist>10</mailinglist>
<format>html</format>
<confirmed>yes</confirmed>
<customfields>
<item>
<fieldid>2</fieldid>
<value>First Name</value>
</item>
<item>
<fieldid>3</fieldid>
<value>Last Name</value>
</item>
</customfields>
</details>
</xmlrequest>
';

$ch = curl_init('http://mydomainname.com/xml.php'); //CHANGE TO THE PATH OF     YOUR IEM INSTALLATION
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$result = @curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false) {die("Error performing request");}
//var_dump($result); //for debugging purposes
//Example of how to display returned data
$xml_doc = simplexml_load_string($result);
if ($xml_doc->status == 'SUCCESS' && empty($xml_doc->data)) {die('Status is         success. Empty response.');}
if ($xml_doc->status == 'SUCCESS') {
    echo 'Response: <br />';
    var_dump($xml_doc->data);
} else {
    echo 'Error is '. $xml_doc->errormessage;
}
}
?>
```

Speaking of just the email field value: I have tried the following:

email
$email
{$email}

and similar combinations for first and last name like:

```
f_name
$f_name
{$f_name}
```

But the problem is that IEM gets input with those characters and doesnt get the actual email, first name or last name input into the iDev form at sign up.

Any help much appreciated.

Ive checked at https://www.interspire.com/emailmarketer/pdf/XMLApiDocumentation.pdf

But cant get anything working. Much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like perl code. If it is, it's probably worth making that clear.

Comment: Actually having said that - it looks a bit like perl, but has `echo` which definitely isn't.

Comment: Satya solved it thanks though. Sorry, its php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml formation needs to be:

```
$xml = '<xmlrequest>
<username>admin</username>
<usertoken>79fc84383811o000fggYYgsui41e5eb</usertoken>
<requesttype>subscribers</requesttype>
<requestmethod>AddSubscriberToList</requestmethod>
<details>
<emailaddress>'.$email.
'</emailaddress>
<mailinglist>10</mailinglist>
<format>html</format>
<confirmed>yes</confirmed>
<customfields>
<item>
<fieldid>2</fieldid>
<value>'.$f_name.'</value>
</item>
<item>
<fieldid>3</fieldid>
<value>'.$l_name.'</value>
</item>
</customfields>
</details>
</xmlrequest>
';
```

in order to inject values of `$email, $f_name,$l_name` in your code

Comment: Il try that now. Thanks for the response I appreciate it.

Comment: WOW, AWESOME Satya - Thanks So Much I Really Appreciate it. worked first time now problem.